# Goroutine in for loop causes unexpected behavior

Tags: go, concurrency

I was doing the [Web Crawler Exercise](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/10) in A Tour of Go.

I was trying to use concurrent Mutex to solve the question, based on a solution found [here](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/notes/crawler.go). I modified it to fit the pre-defined signatures in the original question. However, the crawler stops at the second level of the URL tree. During debugging, the different behaviors of the print statements completely confused me:

```golang
    var done sync.WaitGroup
    for _, u := range urls {
        done.Add(1)
        fmt.Printf("enter: %s\n", u) // here
        go func(url string) {
            defer done.Done()
            Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, f)
        }(u)
    }
    done.Wait()
```

If I put the print statement outside the goroutine, outputs are expected. But I didn't know why it stops there.

```
enter: https://golang.org/pkg/
enter: https://golang.org/cmd/
```

But if I put the print statement inside the goroutine, that is

```
    var done sync.WaitGroup
    for _, u := range urls {
        done.Add(1)
        go func(url string) {
            defer done.Done()
            fmt.Printf("enter: %s\n", u) // here
            Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, f)
        }(u)
    }
    done.Wait()
```

The output becomes

```
enter: https://golang.org/cmd/
enter: https://golang.org/cmd/
```

I have two questions:

1. In the second case, why `enter: https://golang.org/cmd/` gets printed twice?
2. Why does the Crawl function stop at an error, instead of keeping traversing the URL tree?

PS: the second question might be related to the first one. I intentionally made `u` instead of `url` inside the goroutine to reproduce the bug that confused me.

Below is my modified solution

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Fetcher interface {
    // Fetch returns the body of URL and
    // a slice of URLs found on that page.
    Fetch(url string) (body string, urls []string, err error)
}

type fetchState struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    fetched map[string]bool
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, f *fetchState) {
    // TODO: Fetch URLs in parallel.
    // TODO: Don't fetch the same URL twice.
    // This implementation doesn't do either:
    f.mu.Lock()
    already := f.fetched[url]
    f.fetched[url] = true
    f.mu.Unlock()
    
    if already {
        return
    }
    
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
    
    var done sync.WaitGroup
    for _, u := range urls {
        done.Add(1)
        go func(url string) {
            defer done.Done()
            fmt.Printf("enter: %s\n", u)
            Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, f)
        }(u)
    }
    done.Wait()
    
    return
}

func makeState() *fetchState{
    f := &fetchState{}
    f.fetched = make(map[string]bool)
    return f
}

func main() {
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, makeState())
}

// fakeFetcher is Fetcher that returns canned results.
type fakeFetcher map[string]*fakeResult

type fakeResult struct {
    body string
    urls []string
}

func (f fakeFetcher) Fetch(url string) (string, []string, error) {
    if res, ok := f[url]; ok {
        return res.body, res.urls, nil
    }
    return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("not found: %s", url)
}

// fetcher is a populated fakeFetcher.
var fetcher = fakeFetcher{
    "https://golang.org/": &fakeResult{
        "The Go Programming Language",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/": &fakeResult{
        "Packages",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/cmd/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/os/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/": &fakeResult{
        "Package fmt",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
    "https://golang.org/pkg/os/": &fakeResult{
        "Package os",
        []string{
            "https://golang.org/",
            "https://golang.org/pkg/",
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Fix what I assume is a typo to address the first question: change the argument names in the anonymous goroutines from `url` to `u`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks for pointing this out. That's part of the question. I am extremely confused about why `https://golang.org/cmd/` gets accessed twice. My understanding is that it should only be printed once.

Comment: The [FAQ](https://go.dev/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) explains why a value is printed twice.  Rename argument `url` to `u` to fix the data race.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

In you function, you defined `url` as the parameter, but kept using `u` inside of it.
The loop variable u captured by func literal.

Try doing this:

```
    var done sync.WaitGroup
    for _, u := range urls {
        done.Add(1)
        go func(url string) {
            defer done.Done()
            fmt.Printf("enter: %s\n", url)  // <- check the difference
            Crawl(url, depth-1, fetcher, f) // <- check the difference
        }(u)
    }
    done.Wait()
```

For why the same value was being printed with the `u` variable, this is a very common mistake:  https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

In short, the go is passing a single variable by reference to the goroutines. When they execute, they are probably going to find the last value of the iteration in it.

I found this neat article that explains it in detail: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/go-internals-capturing-loop-variables-in-closures/

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. That's part of the question. If I change `url` to `u`, why `https://golang.org/cmd/` gets accessed twice? In my understanding, `u` should be `https://golang.org/pkg/` in the first time the loop gets executed, and then it should be `https://golang.org/cmd/`.

Comment: @Liao-LiaoLiu I've just complemented my answer ! Hope it helps!